# Add directory ignore to PHPStorm

Tags: php, svn, phpstorm

How do I add a folder to the ignore list? In PHPStorm I right-click on the folder->Subversion->set property I select Property name of:svn:ignore and set the property to folder1/folder2/* in the hope that all files in that folder will be ignored but when I want to do a check-in the files that I changed in that folder is in the list to be checked in. How can I exclude a whole folder from check-in? I am working on a Windows7 machine (if that matters)

I am using PHPStorm 6.0.1

Comment: havent worked with phpstorm, what about just ignore it using regular svn command and see if phpstorm respects that?

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: I have no idea how to ignore it using regular SVN commands. I am using PHPStorm 6.0.1 on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Are the files you want to ignore already managed by Subversion, and you're trying to undo that?

Comment: Yes, they are checked into SVN but I do not want them changed. These are config files and locally I change them for my environment, I do not want that checked into SVN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the directory -> Mark Directory As -> Excluded

Answer (score 0):

Try right-click on the folder then Subversion->Ignore.

Comment: Nope. It is available but as soon as I try to click on it PHPStorm grey's it out and it is not clickable.

Comment: there is an issue if file or folder was already added to changelist or repository.
read more here:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206933115-Ignore-committing-certain-SVN-files-