# How to ignore a specific phar file under a PhpStorm project?

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm

I have a `composer.phar` under my Symfony project.
I shall not delete this file.

PhpStorm analyzes this file to index its contained functions and classes.
This file is indexed and I see some troubles like "Multiple declaration".

[image]

[image]

I know [how to ignore a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219186/add-directory-ignore-to-phpstorm), but I'm searching how to ignore a specific `phar`file to avoid indexing.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42272429/phpstorm-ignore-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For phar extension file:**

Such file is shown as plain text in the editor, and is marked with a special icon Plain text file in the Project Tool Window.

In the context of a PHP project, you can also exclude entire **PHP archives** (phar files) to **prevent multiple declaration conflicts** between classes in a phar archive and the corresponding classes in the installed vendors directory. Right-click on file and select "*Exclude phar from project*"

[image: Contextual menu screenshot]

**For any file extension:**

If you mark the file as `plain` file then PhpStorm will ignore it.

1. Select the file from the Project Tool Window
2. Select *Mark as plain text*

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second part of your description helps me a lot!